# Firebase data to RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to display values from sensor to RecyclerView, so i wrote some standard code for realisation of RecyclerView. But i have that error:

```
    com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Failed to convert value of type java.lang.Double to String
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.convertString(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:408)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.deserializeToClass(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:199)
 ....
```

My db:

[image]

And my classes:

**SensorModel**

```
public class SensorModel {

    String  temp, hum, pressure, time;



    public SensorModel()
    {

    }
    public SensorModel(String  temp, String  hum, String  pressure, String  time) {
        this.temp = temp;
        this.hum = hum;
        this.pressure = pressure;
        this.time = time;


    }
}
```

**SensorAdapter**

```
 public  class SensorAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SensorAdapter.SensorViewHolder> {
        private List<SensorModel> list;

        public SensorAdapter(List<SensorModel> list) {
            this.list = list;
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public SensorViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            return new SensorViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.sensorlist,parent,false));
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull SensorViewHolder sensorViewHolder, int i) {

            SensorModel sensor = list.get(i);

            sensorViewHolder.textTemp.setText(sensor.temp);
            sensorViewHolder.textHum.setText(sensor.hum);
            sensorViewHolder.textPress.setText(sensor.pressure);
            sensorViewHolder.textData.setText(sensor.time);
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return 0;
        }

        class SensorViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
        {
            TextView textTemp, textHum, textPress, textData;

            public SensorViewHolder(View itemView)
            {
                super(itemView);
                textTemp = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_temp);
                textHum = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_hum);
                textPress = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_press);
                textData = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textData);
            }
        }
    }
```

And **MainActivity**

```
database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        reference = database.getReference("sensor");

        result = new ArrayList<>();
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.sensorlist);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        llm.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(llm);

        adapter = new SensorAdapter(result);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    .....
     Query queryRecycler = reference.limitToLast(5);
        queryRecycler.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {

            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousKey) {
               result.add(dataSnapshot.getValue(SensorModel.class));
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

        });
```

So i changed type of variables from SensorModel to Double and Long and converted them in SensorAdapter in onBindViewHolder method to String, but it doesn't help. I received errors:Double to String or Long to String and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the following :

```
    String  temp, hum, pressure, time;



    public SensorModel()
    {

    }
    public SensorModel(String  temp, String  hum, String  pressure, String  time) {
        this.temp = temp;
        this.hum = hum;
        this.pressure = pressure;
        this.time = time;


    }
```

into this:

```
    Double temp, hum, pressure, time;



    public SensorModel()
    {

    }
    public SensorModel(Double temp, Double hum, Double pressure, Double time) {
        this.temp = temp;
        this.hum = hum;
        this.pressure = pressure;
        this.time = time;


    }
```

Since in your database, you have the values of type double, then to be able to do `dataSnapshot.getValue(SensorModel.class)` you need to have the same type in both the database and your model class.

Comment: i tried this, but in class SensorAdapter I can't do setText method because it accepts only String type. I talk about onBindViewHolder method:
sensorViewHolder.textTemp.setText(sensor.temp);
"Cannot resolve method 'setText(java.lang.Double)"

Comment: then add to your database String values and when retrieving parse them to double

Comment: but i can't change types in firebase db, i think Firebase itself determines data types

Comment: check this https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference.html#setValue(java.lang.Object) you can have the types specified in link in the database, you need to use `String` type in the `setValue` and you would have String data types in the database

Comment: I tried this:
String result = String.valueOf(sensor.temp);
sensorViewHolder.textTemp.setText(result);
I have no errors now, but for some reason nothing is displayed in recyclerview.

Comment: add a log to check if you are retrieving the value or not